# Can't create AOuth certificate (Resolved - some browser not displaying the page correctly)

Tags: google-oauth

I am getting this error when trying to create the OAuth certificate.

The OAuth screen was already configured as I was expected to do that...

https://www.make.com/en/help/connections/connecting-google-services-using-a-custom-oauth-client

https://www.make.com/en/help/app/google-photos

Now trying to generate he certificate and when I "Create Credentials - OAuth client ID" this what loads on in the frame below:

Failed to load.
There was an error while loading /apis/credentials/oauthclient?previousPage=%2Fapis%2Fcredentials%3Fproject%3Dindustrial-net-......&project=industrial-net-....... Please try again.

It may be a browser or network issue. Go to the loading issues help page  to troubleshoot the issue.

Tried different browsers and redo the steps again as described in the documentation below.

Tried to generate standard API Keys to see if that works, and that worked fine. But the OAuth key gives me the error message.

The consent screen was filled in completely, including name and user etc. I was not able to upload the logo, it says so I saved the consent screen without a logo. Could the missing logo be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The Chrome browser I used didn't display the page properly. There is a drop down menu on that page that is expected, the menu is to select the type of application. That menu and page doesn't load in the browser.

Tried different browser on different machine and there it is loading all right.
This is a new issue, wasn't an issue in the previously as I accessed Cloud Console without issues.